# close serial port in C

Tags: c, embed

windows 7
I have built a project in C to make a dll, whcih could be used in a big program written by python.

```
static HANDLE hCom = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;


unsigned int g_dldtool_exit_code = 0;//can not be written by other threads.



hCom = CreateFile( commPort,
                   GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                   0,    // must be opened with exclusive-access
                   NULL, // default security attributes
                   OPEN_EXISTING, // must use OPEN_EXISTING
                   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,    // overlapped I/O
                   NULL  // hTemplate must be NULL for comm devices
                 );




if (hCom == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
// Handle the error.
    TRACE ("CreateFile failed with error %d", GetLastError());
    g_dldtool_exit_code = 1;
    goto _exit;
}



if (hCom != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    unconfig_serial_port();

    fSuccess = CloseHandle(hCom);
```

I have used

```
if (hCom != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    unconfig_serial_port();

    fSuccess = CloseHandle(hCom);
```

to close the serial port, but the if condition can not be meet every time program goes here, so the serial port can not be closed.
When I annotate the if condition， error occurs: [ERROR showed when building dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZaGC.jpg)

How could I close the
serial port？

The full code could be download here：
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kk2sc3r6pmmh7tt/download_main.c?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

The error you are reporting seems to be due to a problem in the syntax. 
Maybe when you comment out the "if" statement you remove a open bracket "{" but do not remove the close bracket "}". 
Concerning why the code does not meet the if statement condition, it is difficult to say from those pieces of code.

Comment: Thank you， I have added the link to the while code.pls help me to see why serial port can not  be closed.